# Can OR || operators be used to dynamically select a field by name? Importing messy data

Tags: r, select, field, uniqueidentifier, fread

The goal is to produce some R code that'll allow others (members of the public) to easily interact with the FDA side effects archive to develop data mining protocols, rather than having to decipher the anomalies within it themselves before getting started. This could be useful for changing the landscape of miss sold or ineffective drugs, unknown or concealed side effects, etc; open source surveillance.

The data set can get messy. Almost everything that can change, does change; folders for the zip files, zip filenames themselves, folder names within the zips, filenames within the zipped folders, the field names change within the records and there are line anomalies (records broken over two lines). It gets messier still within but I can solve a lot of the issues actually within the data sets to simplify them for others; e.g. drug name simplification etc.

I'm on the home stretch but am struggling with the field names. I'd hoped I could simply assign an OR statement for the column selection with fread and drop it into the FOR loop I'm using to uncompress the originals:

```
#normal
outcomes <- fread('verbatim.basename', sep = '$', header = TRUE, na.strings = '',
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, verbose = TRUE, 

#attempting to select from one or the field name for column import
select = c('ISR' || 'primaryid', 'OUTC_COD' || 'outc_code'),  
col.names = c(ISR || primaryid = 'patient.id', OUTC_COD' || 'outc_code = 'outcome.code'),

#normal
encoding = 'UTF-8', quote = '\'',  strip.white = TRUE, fill = TRUE,
blank.lines.skip = FALSE, showProgress = TRUE)
```

But:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "                  fill = TRUE,"
```

'verbatim.basename' is the the file name I'm obtaining in the loop. I've been trying to get it to work outside the loop explicitly stating the file name, which works fine without the OR statements in there, then tried also adding the multiple selection field names. I've tried re-arranging it a few different ways but would really appreciate any help.

To give a further idea of the problem:

```
#these are some of the field header extracts
ISR$OUTC_COD    
primaryid$caseid$outc_code  
primaryid$caseid$outc_cod
```

I can actually correct for these as I know which are which in all the files, how they relate and that they don't collide. The end aim was to produce a 'key' to undo the changes, such that if a character string was called in the select it would contain the field headers required to collect the field; e.g.

```
patient.id <- 'ISR', 'primaryid'
outcome.code <- 'OUTC_COD', 'outc_code', 'outc_cod'
```

So I could then:

```
#install.packages('gtools')
#require('gtools')
field.key.to.find <- ask('select field')
ifelse(field.key.to.find == 'patient.id', patient.id,
       ifelse(field.key.to.find == 'outcome.code', outcome.code, re-ask)
```

And drop that into the fread in place of the select,

I have tried two entirely different solutions to this problem. One was to (manually) re-structure the entire data set. Which took a long time. The other was to explicitly state every single fread.

Both work, but neither is particularly great. The first means anyone else using the code needs to have the re-strucured data sets. The second is highly restrictive to specific imports.

I'm also open to suggestions for trying a different import approach. I've been wondering if sqldf would solve a lot of this. I've been trying to stick to data.tables throughout as there is a considerable amount of heavy data transformation to do and they're remarkably quick!

The solution to the line issue isn't something I'm totally happy with as it means I have to hand type each correction.

```
#5814344$1010224901$C$KLOR-CON$1$$$$$$$$
#5814345$1010186646$PS$OPANA ER$1$$$U$U$$$21610$
#5814346$1010186647$PS$ROZEREM$1$ORAL$8MG, QHS, PER ORAL; <--------------------------------------------------- line 65,132.
#8 MG, 1/2 TABLET QHS, PER ORAL ;  8 MG, 1/4 TABLET QHS, PER ORAL ;   8 MG, QHS,$D$D$C11806$20071201$21782$ <- the rest of line 65,132 on line 65,133.
#5814346$1010225044$C$SEROQUEL$1$$$$$$$$
#5814346$1010225045$C$KLONOPIN$1$$$$$$$$

drugs_temp <- readLines('faers\\ascii\\DRUG08Q3.TXT',-1)
drugs_temp[65132] <- '5814346$1010186647$PS$ROZEREM$1$ORAL$8MG, QHS, PER ORAL;8 MG, 1/2 TABLET QHS, PER ORAL ;8 MG, 1/4 TABLET QHS, PER ORAL ;8 MG, QHS,$D$D$C11806$20071201$21782$'
drugs_temp[276543] <- '5871230$1010430059$SS$DOMINAL /00018902/ (DOMINAL FORTE - PROTHIPENDYL) 80 MG (NOT SPECIFIED$2$ORAL$(80 MG 1X NOT THE PRESCRIBED AMOUNT ORAL)$D$D$$$$'
drugs_temp[369369] <- '5897624$1010500442$PS$INNOHEP$1$SUBCUTANEOUS$(1000 IU,DAILY), SUBCUTANEOUS$N$D$$$20484$'
drugs_temp <- drugs_temp[-(65133)]
drugs_temp <- drugs_temp[-(276544)]
drugs_temp <- drugs_temp[-(369368)]
writeLines(drugs_temp,'faers\\ascii\\DRUG08Q3fixed.TXT')
rm(drugs_temp)
```

I've on this for fourteen hours so far today but am not getting much further with it.

Thanks for taking a look!

```
a.not.entirely.consistent <- 'uniqueindentifier'
```

Comment: Not a direct answer but I would clean the column headings with something like (names(df) <- `stringr::str_replace(tolower(names(df)), c("(something|outc_co.+)", "(primary.*|isr)"), c("outcome.code", "patient.id"))` where the first vector is a set of regex or matches indicated by | and the second vector lists the corresponding replacement names. Then you can select the columns with a standard name

Comment: Thanks epi, it works with the first sets of field headers, but not the second as there are more of them and 'outc_co' has moved from the second to third position. (ISR$OUTC_COD) goes to (primaryid$caseid$outc_code) then (primaryid$caseid$outc_cod).

Comment: Just as update, my interim solution to this has been to write a readLines writeLines loop to edit the first line of every file. But if there is any other solution I'd still be interested; although this works and seems suitable if it only needs doing once (to edit an archive for use), it also significantly slows down the code initially by comparison with using purely fread.